# The operator + is undefined for the argument type(s) void, String in Java

Tags: java, string, undefined

```
import java.util.Scanner;

    public class Fraction {
        int numerator;
        int denominator;
    
    public Fraction(int n,int d)
    {
        this.numerator=n;
        this.denominator=d;
    }

    static void printFraction(Fraction F)
    {
        System.out.print(F.numerator+"/"+F.denominator);
    } //the function which print object to fraction. ex) parameter=obj1, print 1/2
    

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int num1, num2, num3, num4;
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        

    enter code here
        System.out.print("fraction1(numerator,denominator) input:");
        num1=scanner.nextInt();
        num2=scanner.nextInt();
        Fraction obj1=new Fraction(num1,num2);
        System.out.print("fraction2(numerator,denominator) input:");
        num3=scanner.nextInt();
        num4=scanner.nextInt();
        Fraction obj2=new Fraction(num3,num4);
        System.out.print("-----------------------");
        
        System.out.printf(printFraction(obj1)+"+"+printFraction(obj2)+"="); // the problem!
        scanner.close();
    }
```

the statement "The operator + is undefined for the argument type(s) void, String" occur continuously!
Could you tell me anything to resolve this problem?

Comment: `printFraction()` is a void method. It doesn't return anything. What would you expect the `+` operator to do in this case? I suspect you don't want to print in `printFraction()` - I suspect instead you want to override the `toString()` method and return `numerator + "/" + denominator`...

Answer (score 0):

This is because `printFraction` returns `void` which is a type with no value. What you actually need is calling `printFraction` **and then** print something else, etc:

```
printFraction(obj1);
System.out.print("+");
printFraction(obj2);
System.out.print("=");
```

You are actually using sequence of **instructions** (an instruction to print an object, followed by an instruction to print a string, etc).

But, you probably want to be able to print a `Fraction` as you do for `int` or `double`, like:

```
System.out.println(obj1+"+"+obj2+"=");
```

then for this Java lets you redefine that method `toString` that can be used when your object needs to be prenseted as a `String` (especially in printing methods). This define the following instance method:

```
@Override
public String toString() {
    return this.numerator + "/" + this.denominator;
}
```

This way you can construct an **expression** that build a `String` from various objects, and then print the result of that expression.